# How can I build a web app that displays in another app, using only a embed script

Tags: html

Some web applications, such as feedback and survey tools, are able to embed themselves in another HTML application by using only a simple script reference. That script reference pulls in additional code and HTML to display a modeless dialog or an icon which can be pressed which causes a new dialog in shown in the hosting web page.
How would one code a “minimal-footprint” application such as this? Are there open source tools that make this easier?

An example similar to what I want to do is shown on this Survey Monkey page https://www.surveymonkey.com/curiosity/3-easy-ways-survey-website-visitors/, (but I'm not doing surveys.)

I would prefer not to use an iFrame or embed.  My app is ReactJS-based, if that influences the answer.

Comment: create a Vue.js component. load it via js

Comment: Interesting idea @DeanVanGreunen.  Any pointers to sample code or articles on how that might work?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. design your html code (have the parent/root html ewlemnt be a div, and not the body or html, also exclude head, meta and other header related stuff.
2. design your css code
3. design the dynmiac js code for this site.
4. Compile all html, css and javascript into a single minified js file, this then can be included in any page with an HTML script tag.

(steps 1, 2 and 3)
example HTML:

```
<div class="app-root">
    <label for="num1">
         <span>Number 1</span>
    <input id="num1" placeholder="0" value="0"/>
    </label>
    <label for="num2">
         <span>Number 2</span>
    <input id="num2" placeholder="0" value="0"/>
    </label>
    <label for="calc_btn">
    <button id="calc_btn">Calculate</button>
    </label>
    <label for="output">
         <span>Sum: </span>
    <input id="output" placeholder="0"/>
    </label>
</div>
```

example CSS:

```
.app-root {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

example JS:

```
document.getElementByID('calc_btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
     let num1 = document.getElementByID('num1').value;
     let num2 = document.getElementByID('num2').value;
     let sum = num1 + num2;
     document.getElementByID('output').value = sum;
});
```

STEP 4 - part 1

## convert your html into js,

```
var app_root = document.createElement("div");
app_root.classList.add("app-root");

let label_num1 = document.createElement("label");
let label_num1_span = document.createElement("span")
label_num1_span.innerHTML = "Num 1";
let label_num1_input = document.createElement("input")
label_num1_input.id = "num1";
label_num1_input.placeholder = 0;
label_num1_input.value = 0;

label_num1.append(label_num1_span);
label_num1.append(label_num1_input);

let label_num2 = document.createElement("label");
let label_num2_span = document.createElement("span")
label_num2_span.innerHTML = "Num 2";
let label_num2_input = document.createElement("input")
label_num2_input.id = "num2";
label_num2_input.placeholder = 0;
label_num2_input.value = 0;

label_num2.append(label_num2_span);
label_num2.append(label_num2_input);


let label_btn = document.createElement("label");
let label_btn_input = document.createElement("input")
label_btn_input.id = "calc_btn";
label_btn_input.value = "Calculate";

label_btn.append(label_btn_input );


let label_output = document.createElement("label");
let label_output_span = document.createElement("span")
label_output_span.innerHTML = "Output";
let label_output_input = document.createElement("input")
label_num1_input.id = "output";
label_num1_input.placeholder = 0;
label_num1_input.value = 0;

label_num1.append(label_num1_span);
label_num1.append(label_num1_input);

app_root.append(label_num1);
app_root.append(label_num2);
app_root.append(label_btn);

document.body.append(app_root); // or you could use document.write();
```

STEP 4 - part 2

## convert your ccs into js

```
let global_root_style = document.createElement('style');
global_root_style .type = 'text/css';
global_root_style .innerHTML = '.app-root {margin: 0; padding: 0;}';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(global_root_style);
```

STEP 4 - part 5

## join all parts from step 4 together such that into a function like this.

```
(function() {
   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   // First Register CSS
   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   let global_root_style = document.createElement('style');
   global_root_style .type = 'text/css';
   global_root_style .innerHTML = '.app-root {margin: 0; padding: 0;}';
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(global_root_style);
   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   // Then Register HTML
   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   var app_root = document.createElement("div");
   app_root.classList.add("app-root");
   let label_num1 = document.createElement("label");
   let label_num1_span = document.createElement("span")
   label_num1_span.innerHTML = "Num 1";
   let label_num1_input = document.createElement("input")
   label_num1_input.id = "num1";
   label_num1_input.placeholder = 0;
   label_num1_input.value = 0;
   label_num1.append(label_num1_span);
   label_num1.append(label_num1_input);
   let label_num2 = document.createElement("label");
   let label_num2_span = document.createElement("span")
   label_num2_span.innerHTML = "Num 2";
   let label_num2_input = document.createElement("input")
   label_num2_input.id = "num2";
   label_num2_input.placeholder = 0;
   label_num2_input.value = 0;
   label_num2.append(label_num2_span);
   label_num2.append(label_num2_input);
   let label_btn = document.createElement("label");
   let label_btn_input = document.createElement("input")
   label_btn_input.id = "calc_btn";
   label_btn_input.value = "Calculate";
   label_btn_input.type="button";
   label_btn.append(label_btn_input );
   let label_output = document.createElement("label");
   let label_output_span = document.createElement("span")
   label_output_span.innerHTML = "Output";
   let label_output_input = document.createElement("input")
   label_num1_input.id = "output";
   label_num1_input.placeholder = 0;
   label_num1_input.value = 0;
   label_num1.append(label_num1_span);
   label_num1.append(label_num1_input);
   app_root.append(label_num1);
   app_root.append(label_num2);
   app_root.append(label_btn);
   document.body.append(app_root); // or you could use document.write();
   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   // Then Register JS
   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   document.getElementById('calc_btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
      let num1 = document.querySelector('#num1').value;
      let num2 = document.querySelector('#num2').value;
      let sum = num1 + num2;
      document.querySelector('#output').value = sum;
   });
})()
```

then minimize the step 4 joined output code into a script file, you can use this site https://javascript-minifier.com/

the minimized output will look like this:

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Minimized output code
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
!function(){let e=document.createElement("style");e.type="text/css",e.innerHTML=".app-root {margin: 0; padding: 0;}",document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e);var t=document.createElement("div");t.classList.add("app-root");let n=document.createElement("label"),a=document.createElement("span");a.innerHTML="Num 1";let l=document.createElement("input");l.id="num1",l.placeholder=0,l.value=0,n.append(a),n.append(l);let c=document.createElement("label"),d=document.createElement("span");d.innerHTML="Num 2";let u=document.createElement("input");u.id="num2",u.placeholder=0,u.value=0,c.append(d),c.append(u);let p=document.createElement("label"),m=document.createElement("input");m.id="calc_btn",m.value="Calculate",m.type="button",p.append(m);document.createElement("label");document.createElement("span").innerHTML="Output";document.createElement("input");l.id="output",l.placeholder=0,l.value=0,n.append(a),n.append(l),t.append(n),t.append(c),t.append(p),document.body.append(t),document.getElementById("calc_btn").addEventListener("click",function(){let e=document.querySelector("#num1").value+document.querySelector("#num2").value;document.querySelector("#output").value=e})}();
```

***Notice: there is a bug in my js code, around the value property of the getelementbyid call***

Comment: @BrianCragun No Probs bro